# Why does removing cheese-common removes a bunch of ubuntu essential package?

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

I'm trying to remove some bloatware and when i tried to purge cheese-common bunch of things that I think essential to ubuntu will be removed.

I'm using 14.04LTS

Trying to follow this guide on what to remove  [Link](http://sysadmin-innovations.blogspot.com/2014/04/ubuntu-1404-bloatware-removal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `libcheese7` and `libcheese-gtk23` depend on `cheese-common`, and both `unity-control-center` and `gnome-control-center` (among other things) depend on those two libraries. I would say the control center(s) are required, so you were right in bringing this question up.

In short, you can't remove `cheese-common` in Ubuntu 14.04 without effectively breaking your system.

Comment: +1 You should check with `apt-get purge <PACKAGE_NAME> -s` first to see what packages will be removed. This will tell you that the `cheese` package itself is all you can safely remove.

Answer (score 2):

> sudo apt-get remove cheese

This will remove just the cheese package itself. I.e it does not remove any other packages unless you opt to.